# How do I authorize connections to non-VPC EC2 instances from the instances in a VPC via the igw-xxxx Internet Gateway?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I've got many ec2 instances and recently added a Virtual Private Cloud at amazon too.  On the VPC subnet 10.0.0.0/8 the host 10.0.0.88 can reach the internet at large through an Internet Gateway Device igw-xxxxxx, but I don't know how to authorize that host to access my non-VPC ec2 instances in the outside-the-VPC security group rules.

I'm used to authorizing specific source IPs or the names of other ec2 security groups to connect to the non-VPC hosts, but I can't figure out how to whitelist the VPC host.  Whitelisting 10.0.0.88 doesn't make sense as that IP isn't valid outside the VPC, whitelisting igw-xxxxxx gets me "no such security group".  I *can* whitelist the host if I assign it an Elastic IP, but then the traffic isn't going directly internal to the aws structure.

The FAQ makes this sound possible:

> Q. Can Amazon EC2 instances within a
>   VPC communicate with Amazon EC2
>   instances not within a VPC?
>
> A. Yes. If an
>   Internet Gateway has been configured,
>   Amazon VPC traffic bound for Amazon
>   EC2 instances not within a VPC
>   traverses the Internet Gateway and
>   then enters the public AWS network to
>   reach the EC2 instance.

-- http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#S7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the 10.0.0.88 instance to access the Internet (or EC2) via the Internet Gateway (IGW), the instance either needs to have an associated Elastic IP Address or needs to be talking through a NAT instance (which has an Elastic IP Address).

To lock down an EC2 security group to allow traffic from the VPC instance, specify the allowed source as the Elastic IP Address from either the instance itself or the NAT instance, as discussed above (ex. 192.0.2.25/32).

Comment: Really, there's no way to route entirely with 10.0.0.0/8 spaces (recognizing that the VPC and ec2's own 10.* spaces are separate, of course, but I'd think an IGW could have a 10.* IP in each).  We've found that within ec2 going through a public/elastic IP is 2 to 4 times slower on data xfer and I was hoping ec2<->vpc could avoid that.  Can it not?